# Understanding alternate syntax to write direction vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have taken elementary linear algebra before, and I'm retaking it again for a better grade. I am familiar with the concepts, but my homework uses a syntax I'm unfamiliar with. Here is the question:

Write a vector equation of the line passing through the given points with the given direction vector.

$$P(1, 0), \vec{d} = \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} ? \\ ? \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} ? \\ ? \end{bmatrix}$$

I've never seen this. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: are you more used to $\vec d=(3,1)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sure, I although I used $\hat{i} \hat{j} \hat{k}$ in my statics class.

Comment: you could think of $\hat i$ as $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\hat j$ as $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Ryan Keep in mind that it doesn't make sense to stick to $i,j,k$ in linear algebra because we aren't limited to $2D$ or $3D$ space

Answer (score 0):

In general, a line is given by the set of all vectors that can be written in the form $\vec a + t\vec b$, for vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ and some $t\in\mathbb R$. For a graphical understanding, consider drawing a vector $\vec{a}$ and consider which vectors can be written in the form $\vec a+t\vec b$. For some fixed $\vec b$, of course $t\vec b$ consists of all "scalings" of $\vec b$, or in other words all vectors in the same (or exactly opposite) direction as $\vec b$. This is a line. Then, adding $\vec a$ to it gives you a line that now passes through $\vec a$.

For your example question, the answer is therefore just $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$